# Angular Frontend only displaying app.component.html

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, bootstrap-5

I'm currently making a frontend to my API and now it's time to make another component.
I've tried everything, even created a app-routing.module.ts, but it only displays my app.component.html !!
I don't get why ??
My app-routing.module.ts :

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { clientprodComponent } from './clientproduct/clientprod.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appTtitle = document.title;

const routes: Routes = [
 {path:"", component: AppComponent},
 {path:"clientprod", component: clientprodComponent},

];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [AppComponent, clientprodComponent]
```

My clientprod.component.ts:

```
import { CloudProductService } from './cloudproduct.service';
import { CloudProduct } from './cloudproduct';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-client',
 templateUrl: './clientprod.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./clientprod.component.css']
})

export class clientprodComponent implements OnInit {
 public cloudProducts: CloudProduct[] | null;
 public editProduct: CloudProduct | null;
 public deleteProduct: CloudProduct | null;
 constructor(private cloudProductService: CloudProductService){}

 ngOnInit(){
   this.getCloudProducts();
 }

   public getCloudProducts():void{
     this.cloudProductService.getCloudProducts().subscribe(
       (response: CloudProduct[]) =>{
         this.cloudProducts = response;
       },
       (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         alert(error.message);
       }
     );
 }


 public onOpenModal(cloudProduct: CloudProduct | null, mode: string): void {
   const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
   const button = document.createElement('button');
   button.type = 'button';
   button.style.display = 'none';
   button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
   if (mode === 'add') {
     button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addProductModal');
   }
   if (mode === 'edit') {
     this.editProduct = cloudProduct;
     button.setAttribute('data-target', '#updateProductModal');
   }
   if (mode === 'delete') {
     this.deleteProduct = cloudProduct;
     button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteProductModal');
   }
   container!.appendChild(button);
   button.click();
 }


}
```

My clientprod.component.spec.ts :

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { clientprodComponent } from './clientprod.component';

describe('clientprodComponent', () => {
 let component: clientprodComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<clientprodComponent>;

 beforeEach(async () => {
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ clientprodComponent ]
   })
   .compileComponents();

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(clientprodComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});
```

I don't get it, I have it imported aswell in my app.module.ts...
Why is it just displaying app.component.html, no matter the url ?

Comment: Try adding your component in the app.module file in the declarations array.

And my advice would be to use the angular cli to generate components.

With ng g c <component-name>

Comment: Okay Sir, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line `bootstrap: [AppComponent],` in your `app.module` ?

This means AppComponent it's the entry point of the application, everything needs to go inside this one.
if you want to load diferent components base on route, you need to:

1. add `<routet-outlet></router-outlet>` to your `app.component.html`
2. add routes as you did

   ```
   const routes: Routes = [
     {path:"clientprod", component: clientprodComponent},
     ];
   ```

   without routing to Appcomponent because all this routing goes inside it.
3. make sure to import `AppRoutingModule` in `AppModule`

Hope it helps :)